# RegExp valida correctamente unicamente la primera vez

Tags: angular, typescript, regex

Les pido su ayuda con esta funcion que me esta dando error al momento de Validar una RegExp.

Tengo un array de datos de tipo string que, cuando hago un foreach, debe validar cada uno de los items del array si cumple con un RegExp.

El codigo es algo similar a esto:

```
let entry = ["Ley9enda Cargo [cuenta] 1", "AHORRO AUTOMATICO PERIODO 19 DIC A 25DICF", 
"C Subleyenda 2", "C Subleyenda 3", "C Subleyenda 4", "C Subleyenda 5"]
const pattern = 
/^[abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ1234567890@#$%&\[\], 
.;]*$/g;

entry.forEach(item => {
    let value = item
    let isValid = pattern.test(value)
    console.log("Es valido? : " + isValid)
})
```

Cuando ejecuto la función, al validar el primer item me manda true, el segundo false, el tercero, true y asi sucesivamente. Esto es un error por que todos los items cumplen con el patrón de RegExp

Me apoyan con esto amigos, por favor

Comment: Por favor, además de convertir tu código a snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) muestra qué textos deberían cumplir con la expresión regular, y cuáles no.

Answer (score 1):

Saca el flag "g", ya que si esta puesto se mueve el index desde donde empieza a revisar y hace que falle entre textos

[Metodo Test](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).